# Tensorflow slice issue with unknown batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to get a slice of the input data, `source`. The input shape is [?, 512, 6] and has this shape as it is fed into an LSTM layer, the batch size is unspecified. My neural network, NN, is non-sequential and I require another layer using a subset of the original input data. Specifically, I want to obtain `source[:, :, feature]` where `feature` is a integer variable.

I can use `raw = Reshape((512*6,))(source)` and pass `raw` into a dense layer and the network will assemble, compile and train. However, when compiling using a subset of the `source` array I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

I have tried a few different things. The original data type of `source` is a numpy array. One attempt was to use:

```
raw = source[:,:,feature]
```

I believe that `tf.slice` should be able to handle this. I have obtained the error as well when using:

```
raw = tf.slice( source, [0,0,feature], [-1,512,1] )
```

I have attempted to use `type()` to try and determine which is the `NoneType` object with no success. How do I obtain a working slice?

Edit:
I have been able to obtain the slice and successfully added to the model using:

```
raw = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,feature])(source)
```

and

```
raw = Lambda(lambda x: tf.slice(x, [0,0,feature], [-1,512,1]))(source)
```

While this works and the model compiles, upon attempting to save I get the error:

```
TypeError: Not JSON Serializable
```

I have found some links discussing this issue and they state that the issue is that one of the layers is not a Keras layer. Their solutions involve using a Lambda layer to resolve the issue. I believe that I have been able to isolate the problem layer to be the Lambda layer, which as far as I can tell is a Keras layer. It is imported using:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution through trial and error. I do not currently know why it works though. Let `source` be the input array to the network and have the shape `[?,width,height]` and the individual `feature` element of interest be between `0` and `height`. First we need to flatten `source` such that it has one dimension. I believe the key to solving the problem is in the `Flatten` layer as it must be making the nature of `flat` different from `source` some how despite the type of `source` and `flat` being the same (`<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`). Now we can use a `Lambda` layer to select the feature that we want based on it's new position within `flat`.

```
flat = Flatten()(source)
subsection = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,feature*width:(1+feature)*width])(flat)
```

The new tensor `subsection` can now be fed into some layer and the network will both compile as well as save correctly.